# Current limiting in a ESC

Tags: integrated-circuit, power-electronics, motor-controller, high-current

How is current limited in high-power circuits such as ESCs, considering that they might provide tens of Amperes of current?

Comment: Welcome! Depends on the ESC, but generally you can just limit the duty-cycle. Can you show a schematic of the ESC in question?

Answer (score 0):

It often isn't limited. Reducing the current is simple enough, just turn down the "throttle" value. But you generally need some circuitry to measure the current, and in a space/cost limited device like an ESC you may not bother.

There's almost always a temp sensor and overtemp shutdown feature which can also handle over-current conditions.

Two common methods of measuring the current are use of a current shunt (cheap, gets hot) and a hall effect sensor (more expensive, requires paying attention to stray magnetic fields).

A 3rd method which is free and wastes no power, but which is also generally inaccurate is to measure the drain voltage when your low side mosfets are on. Essentially using the mosfets themselves as the current shunt. This is sometimes handy to detect extreme overloads.